# How do I remove a certain word in brackets in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, brackets

I have a string:

"Hello, my name is blah blah (goodbye) (hello) (oops)"

How do I remove "(hello)" but leaving the other two bracketed words?

I'm doing this right now in PHP but it removes ALL occurrences of brackets and anything inside them. I want to target a specific word, then remove the word and the surrounding brackets.

```
$newName= trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $name));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use regex for such an easy operation

```
$newName = trim(str_replace("(hello)", "", $name));
```

in order to remove more values, you don't even need to use str_replace multiple times, just pass array to the first argument

```
$remove = array(
    "(oops)",
    "(hello)"
); 
$newName = trim(str_replace($remove, "", $name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$toDelete = array("(hello)", "(bye)");

$neName = trim(str_replace($toDelete, "", $name));
```

This will delete all (hello) and (bye)'s in the text. You can add as many as you like.